# C# Conway's Game Of Life

Tags: c#, list, button, checkbox, collections

I built a version of Conway's game of life as a C# Windows Form Application.
The form contains a TableLayoutPanel and each cell of the table contains a form control.
Initially, I had the following classes:

**Grid**

```
int Rows
int Cols  
List<Row> RowList
```

**Row**

```
List<Cell> CellList
```

**Cell**

```
bool IsAlive
Button b
int ColIndex
int RowIndex
```

The code builds up a grid object, taking the no. of rows and columns as arguments, then places each of the cells button controls onto the form in the relevant row & column of the TableLayoutPanel.
I finished developing the game and all worked ok. My maximum grid size is 50x50 and runs quite smoothly.
Then I thought about it and decided I'd be better using CheckBox control instead of Button controls. This would negate the need for the boolean IsAlive in the Cell class as I could just use the CheckBox checked property. I also decided there was no need for the cell object to contain a row and column index as I could determine these by getting the controls location in the TableLayoutPanel. This also made me think there was no need for the Row class. I could just have a Grid with a collection of Cells.
I re-wrote the application in the new way, thinking it would be a cleaner solution but now it runs much, much slower when it comes to performance.
The main processing code is identical, except originally it had to do:

```
foreach (Row r in RowList)
{
    foreach (Cell c in CellList)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

where now it just does:

```
foreach (Cell c in CellList)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

I can't understand why the second version is so much slower. Is it due to the collection of cells being much larger instead of broken down into rows? Or anything to do with the fact I'm using CheckBox objects instead of buttons?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to keep the underlying data structures (list of cells) and the presentation (buttons / checkboxes) as separate as possible. Otherwise you're coupling your program logic tightly to your display method. For this reason alone, I'm not sure the move to using the 'Checked' property of a checkbox to store the state instead of a bool was the best move.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the constructive criticism. C# is new to me and my first experience with OO programming. My background is IBM iSeries and RPG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the code where you change the "Checked" property so this is a guess, but:

If your algorithm is using a control's "Checked" property frequently, it will be very slow because it will be updating a load of UI stuff when the state of the property changes. It will be wanting to update the display state to show a cross.

If you just use a plain bool, it will be very fast. Using a Control property for a bool will likely be thousands of times slower.

Comment: Agreed - this will be the bottleneck. Worth noting that with a tiny array size like 50x50, there will be almost no time at all spent in the list of cells. All else being equal, changing from rows-and-columns to a plain list of cells will not be a performance issue at all.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Initially, to update cells I had my own method which updated the boolean value and then set the Button background color. Once I changed to use checkbox, the checkbox background color was changed by the checkbox controls methods based on it's checked value. I guess the checkbox method which is executed when the checked value changes must do a lot more processing than what I was doing in my original update method with the Button.